# Consumer surplus for multiple products

Tags: definite-integrals, economics

I want to extend the classical definition of consumer surplus to multi-product case. For a single product, consumer surplus is given as
\begin{equation}
CS=\int_ {p_{market}} ^ {p _{\max}}D(p)dp.
\end{equation}

Suppose I have two products $X$ and $Y$ with interdependent demand, that is the demand for product $X$ is given as a function of price of $X$ and price of $Y$:
\begin{equation}
D_X(p_X,p_Y).
\end{equation}
Similarly, demand of product $Y$ is given as $D_Y(p_Y,p_X)$.

In this case, how can one define the consumer surplus? Will it involve two double integrals?
Thanks!